# How to merge two data frames while excluding the NaN value column?

Tags: python, pandas

if df1 is:

```
       size_a  size_b
0       1       2
1       1       5
2       2       3
3       2       9
4       3       1
5       3       5
6       4       4
```

and df2 is:

```
   size_a  size_b
0     1     2
1     2     NaN
2     3     NaN
```

I want the result as:

```
  size_a size_b
0       1       2
1       2       3
2       2       9
3       3       1
4       3       5
```

To do the intersection I want to consider only Non-Nan values of df2- where ever there is a NaN in df2 that column value should be ignored to perform the intersection.

Comment: If you want to exclude `NaN`, shouldn't the result be just one row where the two df's have size_a=1 and size_b=2? Or is your intent to have `NaN` treated as a wildcard and join to df1 on any value for that column where `NaN` is observed in df2?

Comment: I want NaN to be treated as wildcard, I have seven coulmns in actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is first joining by the column(s) that require a non-wildcard join. This will help reduce the conditional filters you would have to build downstream. In the example above, I see that `size_a` is one of those columns:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='size_a')
```

Next you would want to apply the filter conditions where any of the other columns has a match or where the values of those columns in df2 is `NaN`.

```
new_df = new_df[(new_df['size_b_x'] == new_df['size_b_y']) | new_df['size_b_y'].isnull()]
```

Finally, drop the unnecessary column(s) from df2 (denoted by `_y` as suffix in the column names)

```
new_df = new_df.drop('size_b_y', 1)
```

Comment: This solution is more readable and extendable to more than one columns @Scratch'N'Purr thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I think you can `merge` them twice and `concat` the results:

a. Normal `merge`:

```
part1 = pd.merge(df1, df2)
```

b. Merge the subset of rows with `NaN`s:

```
nans = df2[df2.size_b.isnull()]
part2 = pd.merge(df1, nans[["size_a"]], on="size_a")
```

c. `concat` them

```
pd.concat([part1, part2], ignore_index=True)
```

The result:

```
   size_a size_b
0       1      2
1       2      3
2       2      9
3       3      1
4       3      5
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay one way to do this merge on the first column the use filtering to eliminate non-matching rows.

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on='size_a',suffixes=('','_y'))

df_out.query('size_b_y == size_b or size_b_y != size_b_y').drop('size_b_y',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   size_a  size_b
0       1       2
2       2       3
3       2       9
4       3       1
5       3       5
```

*Note: size_by_y != size_b_y is a neat trick to check for NaN values.*